# Second order cone with quadratic interpretation

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

Could you please help me to understand how the second part of the equation (quadratic form) derived form the first one?

The basic definition of the second-order cone is:

$C = \big\{(x,t) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} | \|x\|_2 \leq t \big\}= \big\{(x,t) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} | x^Tx \leq t^2 \big\}= \Bigg\{
\begin{pmatrix}
    x\\
    t
\end{pmatrix}
\bigg|
\begin{pmatrix}
    x\\
    t
\end{pmatrix}^T
\begin{pmatrix}
    I & 0\\
    0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
    x\\
    t
\end{pmatrix}\leq 0,
t \geq 0\Bigg\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Why don't you try expanding that quadratic form in terms of $x$ and $t$.
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
    x\\
    t
\end{pmatrix}^T
\begin{pmatrix}
    I & 0\\
    0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
    x\\
    t
\end{pmatrix} 
\end{align}
First expand
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
    I_{n\times n} & 0_{n\times 1}\\
    0_{1\times n} & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    x_{n\times 1}\\
    t
\end{pmatrix} 
\end{align}
using the rules of block matrix multipication and do again the same using the term on the left side, then note that $x^Tx=||x||_2^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I made the validation, but I would like to ask if there are general rules(lemmas or theorems) for transforming a general quadratic equation $x^TAx+2bx^T +c$ in a matrix representation. For example, I am aware of `Schur` theorem which may help but I can not make the connection. Thanks again.

Comment: @Thoth When you say a matrix representation, are you asking if we can write the general quadratic equation in a single quadratic form? If you are ready to live with additional variables and constraints  (non-convex) then it is possible. I don't think schur theorem would help in that regard.