# Reducing an SDP to an SOCP

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming, second-order-cone-programming

Consider a linear estimation setting where we have measurements of the following form.

$$ {\bf y} = {\bf H} {\bf x} + {\bf v} $$

where ${\bf y}, {\bf v} \in \mathbb{R}^m$, ${\bf x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and ${\bf H} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. An overdetermined system ($m>n$) is assumed. Minimizing the trace of the estimation error covariance by selecting a set of $k$ measurements from the original set,

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
     \underset{\mu_1, \mu_2, \dots, \mu_m}{\mbox{minimize}} &  \hspace{0.5em} \operatorname{Tr} \Bigg(\Bigg(\sum_{i=1}^m \mu_i {\bf h}_i {\bf h}_i^\top\Bigg)^{-1}\Bigg)\\
     \mbox{subject to} & \hspace{0.5em}  \sum_{i=1}^m  \mu_i = k, \\
                      & \hspace{0.5em}  0 \leq \mu_i \leq 1, \quad i = 1,\dots,m,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

where ${\bf h}_i^\top \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is the $i$-th row of $\bf H$. A variant of this problem is discussed in more detail on Chapter 7 of [Boyd & Vandenberghe](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/) (page 387). The problem can be cast as a [semidefinite program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidefinite_programming) (SDP) of the following form.

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \underset{\mu_1, \mu_2, \dots, \mu_m,\\ u_1,u_2,\dots,u_n}{\mbox{minimize}} &  \hspace{0.5em}  \sum\limits_{j=1}^nu_j\\
     \mbox{subject to} & \hspace{0.5em}  \begin{bmatrix}
         \sum\limits_{i=1}^m \mu_i {\bf{h}}_i{\bf{h}}_i^\top & {\bf{e}}_j \\
         {\bf{e}}_j^\top &  u_j
     \end{bmatrix}
     \succeq 0,  \quad j = 1,\dots, n, \\
     & \hspace{0.5em} \sum\limits_{i=1}^m \mu_i = k, \\
     & \hspace{0.5em} 0 \leq \mu_i \leq 1, \quad i = 1,\dots,m,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where ${\bf u} = [u_1,\dots,u_n]^\top \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and ${\bf e}_j$ is the $j$-th unit vector.

Is there a way to reduce this SDP to a [second-order cone program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_cone_programming) (SOCP)? Some hints or starting points would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are reading  Boyd & Vandenberghe, you may want to take a look at [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33414/339790)

Comment: [Possibly related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2652561/339790)

Comment: Thank you for these tips.